# Response had HTTP status code 400 + No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. - MEAN STACK

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, cors

I need to pass a string to the node and the following response in the browser console:

> Failed to load http://localhost:3003/api/buscarCep: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

I'm using MEAN stack with Angular 1.

My server node:

```
const port = 3003

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const server = express()
const allowCors = require('./cors')
const queryParser = require('express-query-int')

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
server.use(bodyParser.json())
server.use(allowCors)
server.use(queryParser())

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`BACKEND is running on port ${port}.`)
}) 

module.exports = server
```

The server is a node and is on the same machine I'm testing. So it's all local. The CORS policies for my server are as follows:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
  next()
}
```

Factory in angular:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('primeiraApp').factory('apiExterna', [
        '$http',
        'consts',
        ApiExterna
    ])

    function ApiExterna($http, consts) {

        function buscarCep(cep) {
            $http.post(`http://localhost:3003/api/buscarCep`, cep)
                .then(resp => {  
                    console.log(resp)          
                    return null
                }).catch(function (resp) {
                    console.log("erro")
                })
        }

        return { buscarCep }
    }
})()
```

The CEP parameter is received from a controller. So far so good, the problem happens from now on:

Routes in backend:

```
const express = require('express')
const auth = require('./auth')

module.exports = function(server) {

  /*
   * Rotas protegidas por JWT
   */
  const protectedApi = express.Router()
  server.use('/api', protectedApi)

  protectedApi.use(auth)

  // rotas da API

  const alertasService = require('../api/alertas/alertasService')
  alertasService.register(protectedApi, '/alertas')

  const ApiService = require('../api/apiExterna/apiService')
  protectedApi.post('/buscarCep', ApiService.buscarCep)
```

"auth" is a module for application authentication.

Here I should receive the CEP:

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const buscarCep = (req, res, next) => {
    const cep = req.body.cep
}

module.exports = { buscarCep }
```

The strangest thing is that for example, everything on that "alerts" route works, but in that post there is no. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: *“The response had HTTP status code 400”* ← That’s the problem you need to solve — not the the *“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”* problem, which is just a side effect of the response not being a 2xx success but instead a 4xx, because the server sending that response probably only adds your custom-configured response headers to 2xx success responses but not 4xx or 5xx errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use npm library cors which is much easier  [cors-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

you don't need to use express-cors

```
const allowCors = require('./cors')
```